# could not find image data or EI using itextsharp

Tags: vb.net

While extracting text from PDF file using itextsharp iam getting an error "Could not find image data or EI"

I have placed my code and sample file. Kindly do the needful.

```
                        Dim simg,tmp,sImgPDFLst  As String
                        simg = AOTD_SU_20131118_006.pdf
                        Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing 
                        tmp = pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, New pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy())
                        If tmp.Length = 0 Then
                              sImgPDFLst = "Following files are IMAGE PDF" 
                        End If
                        reader.Dispose()
                        reader.Close()
                        reader = Nothing
```

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7KbnFSRWx5ZVNpSkk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET website or web application? If yes, try putting the full URL of the image.

Comment: its an windows application.

Comment: Are you using full paths? For instance "C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\image1.jpg" ?

Comment: s sir iam using full path only..just for information iam posting filename

Comment: is there any solution for this???kindly do the needful

Comment: Take a look at this link http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/parser/InlineImageUtils.cs#l337. The part where there is a while loop, and the "found" variable in the ParseInlineImageSamples() method. Try doing something similar - you should avoid your error implementing reading images in that manner. The code is in C# but you can convert using online free converters.